# Child height % will not follow parent container

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't figure out why the child's height will not be the same as the the parent container on this code. Any ideas?
Both containers are `<div>`

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    min-height: 6rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 12rem;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what does your browser's inspector say about the calculated parent's height value?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set a `height` in the parent or move the `min-height` to the child.